# Variables in other scripts in Unity

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine, scripting

I am trying to create a game in Unity 2d. I have finished most of what I want to do and have moved on to the enemies. The enemies (dragons) come in from different points of screen. To do this I have placed sprite game objects where I want the dragon to spawn. I have made all of these objects a child of another object called DragonAncores. I attached a script to DragonAncores which says this...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DragonTracker : MonoBehaviour {
    // is gold dragon in play?
    public bool GoldDragonInit = false;
    // curently active dragons
    public int DragonCount = 0;
    // defalts to 5
    public int Difficulty = 5;
}
```

I am then attaching a script to each sprite which will eventually summon in a dragon Prefab (containing 2 colliders and an animator) biased of If statment logic derived from the other variables.

Below is the code I am using.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Dragons : MonoBehaviour {
    // same as GoldDragonInit
    bool GoldDragonSpawn = false;
    // same number as DragonCount in DragonTrackeer
    int LiveDragons;
    // same as Difficulty
    int DifLev;
    //get cariables from other script
    DragonAncors.cs.GetComponent.<DragonTracker>() GoldDragonInit = GoldDragonSpawn;

    System.Random RNG= new System.Random();
    void update()
    {
        RSpawn=RNG.Next(0,2)
        DragonType=RNG.Next(0,101)
        if (RSpawn = 1) ;
        {
            if (LiveDragons > DifLev) ;
            {
                if (DragonType > 99) ;
                {
                    // summon regular dragon
                }
                if (DragonType = 100) ;
                {
                    if (GoldDragonSpawn = true) ;
                    {
                        // summon gold dragon
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is throwing up this error list.

[image: Error List]

This shows my hierarchy in unity and the anchor points (the Squair crosshair looking things)

[image: Unity Hierarchy and anchor points]

I have looked for other threads that adress this topic and they all try different methods, none work.

I am using Unity 2018.2.18f1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code here. The following is incorrect.

```
//get cariables from other script
    DragonAncors.cs.GetComponent.<DragonTracker>() GoldDragonInit = GoldDragonSpawn;
```

The correct way to access this, seeing as you said DragonAncors is the parent would be:

```
GetComponentInParent<DragonTracker>().GoldDragonInit = GoldDragonSpawn;
```

This sets the GoldDragonInit Boolean to the value of GoldDragonSpawn. This has to be inside a function, as you have it outside of a function I presume you needed this set on start. Therefore I have placed it in the void Start() function. This is called at the start of the game(loaded scene).

You also do not need semi-colons ; after an if statement, however it does need to appear after every line of difinitive code. The code you have provided should instead look like this.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Dragons : MonoBehaviour {
    // same as GoldDragonInit
    bool GoldDragonSpawn = false;
    // same number as DragonCount in DragonTrackeer
    int LiveDragons;
    // same as Difficulty
    int DifLev;
    void Start()
    {
        // variables from other script
     GetComponentInParent<DragonTracker>().GoldDragonInit = GoldDragonSpawn;
    }
    System.Random RNG= new System.Random();
    void update()
    {
        RSpawn=RNG.Next(0,2);
        DragonType=RNG.Next(0,101);
        if (RSpawn = 1)
        {
            if (LiveDragons > DifLev)
            {
                if (DragonType > 99)
                {
                    // summon regular dragon
                }
                if (DragonType = 100)
                {
                    if (GoldDragonSpawn = true)
                    {
                        // summon gold dragon
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works because DragonTracker is a script in the objects parent. If this was not the case then GetComponentInParent().GoldDragonInit = GoldDragonSpawn; would be replaced like so:

```
[SerializeField]
private GameObject DragonAncors;
void Start()
{
    DragonAncors.GetComponent<DragonTracker>().GoldDragonInit = GoldDragonSpawn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## This is not valid c# code:

```
//get cariables from other script
DragonAncors.cs.GetComponent.<DragonTracker>() GoldDragonInit = GoldDragonSpawn;
```

Why? Because it isn't inside a method.

Also, the comment is wrong. It isn't *getting* a variable (typo, too), its *setting* a variable in another script!

The reason for the first...16 problems Visual Studio is complaining about are because of this line.

At this location you are only allowed to *declare methods, fields, and properties* and you're currently trying to access another class and change one of its members (something you can only do inside a method).

Additionally, you have `.cs` which I assume is because "DragonAnchors.cs is the file name!" which you don't need to do. I'm not sure how to go about rewriting this line (inside `Start()`) as I'm not sure what you're trying to actually do. That is, I don't know where an instance of DragonAnchors actually resides. You're calling `GetComponent()`, which is typically reserved for accessing components attached to game objects, but as you've attempted to do so on a static class reference, I'm not sure if you meant to call it on `this` or on something else.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can get to DragonTracker:

```
DragonTracker dt = GameObject.Find("DragonAncores").GetComponent<DragonTracker>()
Debug.Log(dt.DragonCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of errors there and they may take some steps to go through, but first things first you should clear up the issue with the code you're trying to use being unsupported. Go into the project settings and change the compiler language version as it notes on the 5th error down. This should allow you to use the newer functionality.